# Swift Package Manager, how to handle fixtures?

Tags: swift, fixtures, swift-package-manager

I'm looking to integrate [DVR](https://github.com/venmo/DVR) into my tests for an HTTP request-heavy library I am writing. I'm using Swift Package Manager (on macOS 10.15 using the Xcode 11 Beta) to manage my dependencies and I'm unsure how to include my fixtures generated by DVR into my test target. How do I add my fixtures from DVR to my test target?

I've tried using the default Session configuration as well as attempting to store the fixtures in a Fixtures directory using `Session(outputDirectory: "Fixtures", cassetteName: "example", testBundle: .main, backingSession: .shared)`

My package file is as follows:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.1
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Example",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "Example",
            targets: ["Example"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/venmo/DVR.git", from: "2.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "Example",
            dependencies: []
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ExampleTests",
            dependencies: ["Example", "DVR"]
        )
    ]
)
```

When running my tests, I get the error `[DVR] Persisted cassette at Fixtures/example.json. Please add this file to your test target`

I'm unsure how to add this directory to my test target.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may be impossible as of Swift 5.1. Swift ticket: [SR-2866](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2866)